# 0.1 increment in a While Loop (C Programming)

Tags: c, while-loop, increment, tabular

I am in an introductory C programming class. Our latest project has us writing code to tabulate `x` and `sqrt(x)` values from 1-10 with a 0.1 step using a while loop. When I try to do the 0.1 increment, however, nothing is added to the starting integer 1 and the program runs in an infinite loop. I'll post the code below. Other than it not doing the step, the program runs fine (and works with other increments like 1, etc.). How do I resolve this?

```C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
   int x=1;
   double sq_rt;
   printf("Square Root Table: \n");
printf("Value of X        Square Root of X\n");    
while (x <= 10)
   {
      sq_rt = sqrt (x);     
printf("%6i %20f \n", x, sq_rt);   
x += 1e-1;
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't add 0.1 (a floating point number) to an integer (`x`); declare `x` to be a floating point: `double x = 1;`.

Comment: Yes you can. It just doesn't always do what you expect.

Comment: @MartinTörnwall Yes, but I think for this question, it makes more sense to simply keep it to a "no, you can't.". It'd be good as a full answer to supply the explanation what is happening here.

Comment: So, how should I write it in then? As it is right now, it runs in an infinite loop where it just keep taking the square root of 1

Comment: @FredToews I just put that in the first comment; what do you not understand about that?

Comment: Do I put it within the loop? Because the compiler is giving me an error that I need an integer. I'm sorry, I'm in an intro class.

Comment: @Evert: I disagree. Saying "No, you can't" when it clearly compiles without error is likely to cause more confusion than explaining that it's legal but doesn't do what's expected.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` type will only allow you to store whole numbers (i.e. -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 etc). To store numbers with a decimal point, you'll need a double precision (or `double`) type. Change the first line of `main()` to:

```
double x = 1.0;
```

If you try to add `1e-1` to an `int`, it will convert it to an `int` first - the type of `x` - which when truncated will end up being zero, so you'll never actually add anything to `x`.

Comment: s/rounded/truncated ;)

Comment: Starting with `1.0` and repeatedly adding `1.0` is likely not to reach `10.0` exactly due to rounding errors. (Perhaps that's the point of the exercise?)

Comment: @Keith Thompson Suspect you meant  "adding `0.1`" in your comment.

Comment: @chux: Yes.  Perhaps I was using little-endian notation. 8-)}

Answer (score 1):

The line in your program which reads

```
x += 1e-1;
```

is performing operations equivalent to

```
x = (int)(((double)x) + 0.1);
```

In other words, x is first converted to a `double`, then 0.1 is added to it, resulting in 1.1. This value is then converted to `int`, resulting in a value of 1, which is assigned to x.

The fix is to change the type of `x` to a floating point type such as `float` or `double`.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

the following code is a suggestion on how to perform the desired algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// define the magic numbers, don't embed them in the code
#define UPPER_LIMIT (10.0)
#define STEP_SIZE   (0.1)

int main(void)
{
    double x=1.0;
    double sq_rt;

    printf("Square Root Table: \n");
    printf("Value of X        Square Root of X\n");

    // due to ambiguities in 'real' values, 
    // this loop will iterate approx. 90 times.
    while( x < UPPER_LIMIT )
    {
        sq_rt = sqrt (x);

        // display the two double values
        // note: long float conversion values 
        // because the underlying numbers are double
        // note: blanks for alignment with column headers

        printf("%9.6lf        %16.13lf \n", x, sq_rt);

        // increase base value by increment of 0.1
        x += STEP_SIZE;
    } // end while

   return 0;
} // end function: main
```